# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n$ where $I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{1+nx}dx$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[0,1]$.

Find  $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n$ where $I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{1+nx}dx$.

I have tried it over some specific functions and I think that  $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n=0$.

I think also that we can use that the function is bounded since it is integrable.

I can use a hint (not a solution).

Note: I have just learned definite integrals till now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f$ is supposed to be continuous ?

Comment: No. It is not written in the question.

Comment: Hint: $|I_n|\leq\int_0^1\frac{|f(x)|}{1+nx} dx\leq \int_0^1 \frac{M}{1+nx} dx$ where $M$ is some bound of $|f|$.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, a Riemann integrable function is always bounded. Call this bound $M$. You can thus use $M$ to find an upper bound for $|I_n|$, and then use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: This is the shortest solution, but I'm not sure OP is familiar with Lebesgue integration.